# The length of the curve of intersection of the cylinder $25x^2 + y^2 = 25$ and the plane $x + y + z = 5$

Tags: curves

Find, correct to four decimal places, the length of the curve of intersection of the cylinder $25x^2 + y^2 = 25$ and the plane $x + y + z = 5$.

I have tried this problem multiple times getting the same wrong answer of $44.0992$. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you show the work you did to get this answer?

Comment: x = cost, y = 5 sint, z = 5 - cost - 5sint  0 ≤ t ≤ 2.
I took the derivative of that vector and found the length of that vector. Then I integrated that from 0 to 2π

Comment: I get $\int_0^{2\pi } {\sqrt {\sin ^2 t + 25\cos ^2 t + \left( {\sin t - 5\cos t} \right)^2 } dt = 29.5463 \cdots } $

Comment: Using your method (and WolframAlpha), I got an answer of 29.5464